# Exchanging keystrokes based data among multiple python processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pynput

I am running two separate Processes in my script. First process, p1, starts a oneSecondTimer routine that executes at exactly at 1 second and does some work. Second process, p2, fires off a keyboard listener that, well, listens to the keyboard.

At the moment, I want the p1 process to stop when the user presses the escape key. I tried using a global variable, it didn't work. I tried using a queue, it worked, but it is definitely not the most elegant solution out there. Its actually an ugly workaround which is not going to scale up.

Eventually, the script would have a number of separate parallel processes that would be controlled (not just start/stop) by pressing various keys.
Here's the code,

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        print('escaped!')
        # Stop listener
        return False


def keyboardListener(q):
    with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
    print('Keybord Listener Terminated!!!')
    # Make the queue NOT EMPTY
    q.put('Terminate')


def oneSecondTimer(q):
    starttime = time.time()
    # Terminate the infinite loop if 
    # queue is NOT EMPTY
    while (not q.qsize()):
        print("tick")
        time.sleep(1.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1.0))
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=oneSecondTimer, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=keyboardListener, args=(q,))
    p2.start()
```

Comment: Queue and Pipes are the standard way to exchange data between processes, why you say it's not elegant?

Comment: @toti08 I am not able to pass around the keystrokes from P2 to P1. At the moment, I am only able to check if the queue is empty or not and take the actions accordingly. If I want to take 4 different actions in P1, based on 4 different keystrokes captured in P2, I am not able to do that. More specifically, I am not able to modify the Queue inside the *on_release(key)* sub routine. Any help here would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Well, looking at the document it looks like your `on_release` method can only have one input (the key pressed). Maybe you need a simpler approach to the problem? Like using the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to make this work. 
In the above snippet, when I was calling the

> listener.join()

to the Keyboard Listener event, it was essentially blocking the execution of the rest of the *keyboardListener(q)* process till the *on_release(key)* function *STOPPED*. Because this is exactly what *.join()* is supposed to do. It is a *Blocking call*.

In the following snippet, the *keyboard.listener* thread is simply *started* in the *keyboardListener(q)* process. A *while* loop keeps track of the variable called *fetchKeyPress*. The variable does what the name implies, it fetches the pressed key in the *on_release(key)* subroutine. Key presses fetched by fetchKeyPress are pumped in the Queue called **q** that is shared among the two processes, *keyboardListener(key)* and *oneSecondTimer(q)*. The keyboardListener process runs 4 times as fast as the oneSecondTimer process, has logic to exit the *while* loop and prevents flooding of the queue if the user presses the same key continuously/repeatedly.

The *oneSecondTimer(q)* process runs at every second. If the **q** is not empty, it spits out whatever is there in the **q**. It also has a *while* loop exit logic built into it.

Now I can utilize the data (key presses) acquired by the process **p2** and use it in the other parallel running process **p1**.

**p2** is the *Producer*. **p1** is the *Consumer*.

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

fetchKeyPress = 10

def on_release(key):
    global fetchKeyPress 
    fetchKeyPress = key
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        fetchKeyPress = 0
        print('escaped!')
        # Stop listener
        return False


def keyboardListener(q):
    global fetchKeyPress
    prevKeyFetch = 10    # Keep track of the previous keyPress
    keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release).start()
    while (fetchKeyPress):
        print ('Last Key Pressed was ', fetchKeyPress)
        # Fill the Queue only when a new key is pressed
        if (not (fetchKeyPress == prevKeyFetch)):
            q.put(fetchKeyPress)   
        # Update the previous keyPress
        prevKeyFetch = fetchKeyPress
        time.sleep(0.25)
    print('Keybord Listener Terminated!!!')
    q.put('Terminate')


def oneSecondTimer(q):
    runner = True   # Runs the while() loop
    starttime = time.time()
    while (runner):
        print('\ttick')
        if (not q.empty()): 
            qGet = q.get()
            print ('\tQueue Size ', q.qsize())
            print ('\tQueue out ', qGet)
            # Condition to terminate the program
            if (qGet == 'Terminate'):
                # Make runner = False to terminate the While loop
                runner = False
        time.sleep(1.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1.0))
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=oneSecondTimer, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=keyboardListener, args=(q,))
    p2.start()
```

But I think at the end of the day, I am probably just going to use the https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ library because of the simplicity. Thanks to @toti08 for the suggestion in the comments above.